# sed to replaces space with \space between double quotes

Tags: sed, makefile

I have a dep file in the following format

```
main.o :    "C:/My code/main.c"
"C:/My code/main.c" :
main.o :    "C:\Program Files\xyz\stdio.h"
"C:\Program Files\xyz\stdio.h" :
```

With makefile, I am using sed to remove double quotes and replace backward slash with a front slash. I am using windows and using gmake to build the make file

I am new to sed.
I have figured out sed commands to remove double quotes and replace backward slash with a front slash.

`sed -e "s/\\\/\//g" -e "s/\"//g" main.dep`

```
main.o :    C:/My code/main.c
C:/My code/main.c :
main.o :    C:/Program Files/xyz/stdio.h
C:/Program Files/xyz/stdio.h :
```

Before doing that I want to replace the space with backslash space(\s)
If I replace all the spaces in the file with backslash space(\s) it makes my dep file nonusable.

So before removing double quotes I want to replace the spaces in double quotes with backslash space(\s).

Expected output

```
main.o :    C:/My\ code/main.c
C:/My\ code/main.c :
main.o :    C:/Program\ Files/xyz/stdio.h
C:/Program\ Files/xyz/stdio.h :
```

Can we do it with sed and in makefile?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't really have file names with spaces in `make`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^(([^"]*"[^" ]*")*[^"]*"[^"]*) /\1\n/;ta;s/"//g;y/\\/\//;s/\n/\\ /g' file
```

Replace all spaces in-between double quotes with newlines, remove all double quotes, replace backslashes by forward slashes and replace newlines by a backslash and a space.

Comment: What is this witchcraft?? If you have the time, would you mind adding some explanation of how this works?

Comment: Thanks, @potong. it works in Unix. Could you please explain or provide links to understand the command?

Comment: @mattb in order to replace spaces within double quotes we must first identify characters from the start of the line up to such a space. Thus the substitution regex captures zero or more of non-double quote characters, followed by double quoted strings which do not contain spaces, followed by non-double characters, a double quote and non-double quoted characters, followed by a space. The captured group stays where it is and the space is replaced by a newline. The substitution is repeated until it fails Later on the newlines are replaced by `\ `'s.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it using GNU sed if the double quoted strings contain only one
space to be replaced with `\`  (see below for a way to deal with multiple
spaces):

```
sed 's_\\_/_g; s/\(\".*\) \(.*\"\)/\1\ \2/g; s/\"//g' your_file
```

The way the 3 commands are working is as follows:

- In the first command I'm using the `_` as a delimiter so I don't have to
  escape the `/` characters
- In the second command I remember the stuff in between the above using `\(`
  and `\)`
  (two groups of things separated by a non-remembered space)
- Then replace with the remembered content `\1` and `\2` with the desired `\`
  in between

For the input:

```
main.o :    "C:/My code RIGHT HERE/main.c"
"C:/My code/main.c" :
main.o :    "C:\Program Files\xyz\stdio.h"
"C:\Program Files\xyz\stdio.h" :
```

the command makes:

```
main.o :    C:/My\ code/main.c
C:/My\ code/main.c :
main.o :    C:/Program\ Files/xyz/stdio.h
C:/Program\ Files/xyz/stdio.h :
```

##### Example of 'hacky' repeated command with 3 repeats

If you want to take care of a possible folder with 3 spaces, you can
(hackily...) repeat an adjusted version the second command like so:

```
sed 's_\\_/_g;
s/\(\".*\) \(.*\"\)/\1\\ \2/g;
s/\(\".*[^\]\) \(.*\"\)/\1\\ \2/g;
s/\(\".*[^\]\) \(.*\"\)/\1\\ \2/g; s/\"//g' 
your_file
```

The `[^\]` on subsequent commands prevent us from matching beyond the first `\`

on this input:

```
main.o :    "C:/My code RIGHT HERE/main.c"
"C:/My code/main.c" :
main.o :    "C:\Program Files\xyz\stdio.h"
C:/Program\ Files/xyz/stdio.h :
```

gives:

```
main.o :    C:/My\ code\ RIGHT\ HERE/main.c
C:/My\ code/main.c :
main.o :    C:/Program\ Files/xyz/stdio.h
C:/Program\ Files/xyz/stdio.h :
```

Comment: Thanks mattb for your quick response. As I said I am still learning had some more issues while running your command. I am using windows and GNU sed 4. When I run this I get following error 
sed: -e expression #1, char 43: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Sure mattb. Isn't there a clean way to just extract the data in double-quotes in a temporary buffer,  process it, and replace it?

Comment: got it working with single space
`sed "s_\\_/_g; s/\(\"".*\) \(.*\""\)/\1\ \2/g; s/\""//g" your_file` In windows double quotes `"` needs to be replaced by `\""`

Comment: @vikky, that issue is probably related to the shell that is processing the command.  Inasmuch as it is a little strange for you to be using `sed` on Windows in the first place, it would be helpful if you edited the question to clarify the details of how you are running this.  (Note: with `make` / makefile is not a sufficient description.)  Which `make` are you using?  Which shell?  What command line? From where are your `make` and `sed` coming, since they are not included standard with Windows?

Comment: @vikky ah ok I updated my answer to escape the double quotes (doing the escaping doesn't affect in bash so it's good for both OS's now). I also updated to use the 4 line version of your updated examples.

Comment: @John I have updated the question. I have installed it manually on windows. I use gmake. The makefile is compatible with both Windows and Linux. I wanted to update this auto-generated dep file manually with a makefile as soon as it is generated. The compiler does not provide any ways to do what I want. As a result, I googled for ways to update generated dep file and got the best bet as sed. If you have any other way do let me know to make the above example dep file compatible with gmake